# Java program running on build but not in a fat jar

Tags: java, jar, jasper-reports

I have a java application that uses the Jasper Reports API to generate a PDF. It builds fine but I had to add in some fonts via Netbeans/iReport plugin in order for them to show up when exporting the PDF. On clean and build it's fine and everything works.

But when I build a fat jar (via a few package-for-store lines in the build.xml) the reports won't run. Running via the Terminal, I get this error (sorry for wall of text):

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.<init>(JRBaseFiller.java:124)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.<init>(JRVerticalFiller.java:89)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.<init>(JRVerticalFiller.java:104)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.<init>(JRVerticalFiller.java:62)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.createFiller(JRFiller.java:179)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:108)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:668)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:649)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:971)
    at ie.orderofmalta.OMFinancialsForm.yTDReportBtnActionPerformed(OMFinancialsForm.java:283)
    at ie.orderofmalta.OMFinancialsForm.access$700(OMFinancialsForm.java:30)
    at ie.orderofmalta.OMFinancialsForm$8.actionPerformed(OMFinancialsForm.java:163)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:376)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(BasicMenuItemUI.java:833)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicMenuItemUI.java:877)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3320)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
Caused by: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Input stream not found at : fonts/fontsfamily1406301744789.xml
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontExtensionHelper.loadFontFamilies(SimpleFontExtensionHelper.java:188)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.FontExtensionsRegistry.getExtensions(FontExtensionsRegistry.java:56)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.extensions.DefaultExtensionsRegistry.getExtensions(DefaultExtensionsRegistry.java:110)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRStyledTextParser.<clinit>(JRStyledTextParser.java:83)
    ... 50 more
Caused by: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Input stream not found at : fonts/fontsfamily1406301744789.xml
    at net.sf.jasperreports.repo.RepositoryUtil.getInputStreamFromLocation(RepositoryUtil.java:159)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontExtensionHelper.loadFontFamilies(SimpleFontExtensionHelper.java:183)
    ... 53 more
```

When I added in the fonts, I added them to a jar which I then added to the class path. By the "input stream not found" error I'm guessing this is something to do with those fonts. But everything works fine in the normal clean-and-build process but I can't understand why the fat jar won't work.

Any ideas?

EDIT: Very similar to this [Font Extension for barcode in report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12104794/font-extension-for-barcode-in-report)

Comment: Did you do anything other than adding a .jar file to the clsaspath?  Did you write any code to load these fonts? If so, please edit your question to include that code.  (It would also help to know exactly what version of Jasper Reports you're using.)

Comment: No I just added the jar file. It contains the fonts, a properties file and a fonts.xml file as required by Jasper. What I don't get is that the compiled jar in /dist works just fine but the single fat jar doesn't. I've spent the morning trying different approaches but nothing is working. Why would a single jar not run if the original jar with the separate /lib folder runs fine?

Comment: Are you sure the .xml file has the same path in the unified .jar that it has when packaged in its own .jar?

Comment: yes they're both under /fonts in both jars. I can't understand why the unified jar would ask for an input stream when the normal jar doesn't...

Comment: I'm not familiar with Jasper;  did the solution in the SO question to which you've linked help?  (I don't know what increasing the "size of the component" actually entails.)

Comment: I'm not sure what it means either! I think I'll reply to that question in the hope of getting an update. In the meantime, I managed to get the fat jar to run the report, but then the fonts are not showing! But they are in the normal jar. Must be some kind of bug. Thanks for your help anyway.

Answer (score 7):

I was stuck with this same problem for two days and I could not find anything to help me. I hope this helps anyone facing the same problem.

Here is how I solved the problem.

First of all, the tools being used by me

- Jaspersoft Studio to create my reports 6.0.3
- Jasperreport Library 6.0.3
- Arial Unicode MS, font being embedded
- Netbeans 8.0.2

So, first I modified the file **jasperreports_extension.properties** inside of **jasperreports-6.0.3.jar** and included the following lines

```
net.sf.jasperreports.extension.registry.factory.simple.font.families=net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontExtensionsRegistryFactory
net.sf.jasperreports.extension.simple.font.families.dejavu=net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/fonts.xml
```

For some reason when I was building my jar file there was a conflict between the file **jasperreports_extension.properties** from jasperreports-6.0.3.jar and the one inside jasperreports-fonts-6.0.3.jar and the last one would be overridden.

Now to include my font (Arial Unicode MS) I edited the file **/net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/fonts.xml** and inserted the following code:

```
<fontFamily name="Arial Unicode MS">
    <normal>net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/ArialUnicodeMS/ARIALUNI.TTF</normal>
    <pdfEncoding>Identity-H</pdfEncoding>
    <pdfEmbedded>true</pdfEmbedded>
    <exportFonts>
    </exportFonts>
</fontFamily>
```

After this I included my font inside of jasperreports-fonts-6.0.3.jar.

[image]

Now this is very important, when you are creating your jar file make sure to extract jasperreports-fonts-6.0.3.jar before jasperreports-6.0.3.jar.

Here is my build.xml

```
<target name="-post-jar">
    <jar jarfile="dist2/Reports.jar">
        <zipfileset src="${dist.jar}" excludes="META-INF/*;*.jar;*.txt;*.html" />
        <zipfileset src="lib/jetty-all-9.0.3.v20130506.jar" excludes="META-INF/*;*.txt;*.html" />

        <zipfileset src="lib/lib/jasperreports-javaflow-6.0.3.jar" excludes="META-INF/*;*.txt;*.html" />
        <zipfileset src="lib/jasperreports-fonts-6.0.3.jar" excludes="META-INF/*;*.txt;*.html" />
        <zipfileset src="lib/jasperreports-6.0.3.jar" excludes="META-INF/*;*.txt;*.html" />

        <zipfileset src="lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.34-bin.jar" excludes="META-INF/*;*.txt;*.html" />
        <zipfileset src="lib/commons-javaflow-20060411.jar" excludes="META-INF/*;*.txt;*.html" />
        <zipfileset src="lib/servlet-api-2.4.jar" excludes="META-INF/*;*.txt;*.html" />
        <zipfileset src="lib/javax.servlet-3.0.jar" excludes="META-INF/*;*.txt;*.html" />
        <zipfileset src="lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar" excludes="META-INF/*;*.txt;*.html" />
        <zipfileset src="lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar" excludes="META-INF/*;*.txt;*.html" />
        <zipfileset src="lib/ant-1.7.1.jar" excludes="META-INF/*" />
        <zipfileset src="lib/groovy-all-2.0.1.jar" excludes="META-INF/*" />
        <zipfileset src="lib/commons-digester-2.1.jar" excludes="META-INF/*" />

        <zipfileset src="lib/itextpdf-5.5.0.jar" excludes="META-INF/*" />
        <zipfileset src="lib/itext-pdfa-5.5.0.jar" excludes="META-INF/*" />
        <zipfileset src="lib/apache-commons-lang.jar" excludes="META-INF/*" />
        <zipfileset src="lib/com.lowagie.text-2.1.7.jar" excludes="META-INF/*" />

        <zipfileset src="lib/commons-beanutils-1.9.0.jar" excludes="META-INF/*" />

        <manifest>
              <attribute name="Main-Class" value="Jetty"/>
        </manifest>
    </jar>
</target>
```

Comment: exact the answer I want it. Thanks for the details. I have tried several hours to find out why the custom font library never works. Turns out it is overridden like you mentioned.

Comment: I was facing this problem for 3 days and this was the ideal sotlution. The main cause was the conflict conflict between the file **jasperreports_extension.properties** after create the big jar the last one override all previous file with the same name.

Comment: Thanks a lot it helps me a lot.

Comment: But I got this error -  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/javaflow/core/StackRecorder

Answer (score 2):

What solved it for me was to append the contents of the `jasperreports_extension.properties` file contained in the `jasperreports-6.x.x.jar` to my custom `jasperreports_extension.properties`.

The Problem was that the properties file from the jar got overwritten when creating the fat jar. Obviously JasperReports merges both files at runtime. Since the original content is missing, it causes this slightly misleading error.

Comment: That does it. To be specific though, you need not append all the contents of the default properties file. You only need the following entry: _net.sf.jasperreports.extension.registry.factory.repository=net.sf.jasperreports.repo.DefaultRepositoryExtensionsRegistryFactory_

Answer (score 0):

```
Caused by: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Input stream not found at : fonts/fontsfamily1406301744789.xml at 
net.sf.jasperreports.repo.RepositoryUtil.getInputStreamFromLocation(RepositoryUtil.java:159) at 
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontExtensionHelper.loadFontFamilies(SimpleFontExtensionHelper.java:183) 
... 53 more
```

You need to provide a proper input stream to whatever you want to do here.     If the resource is inside a jar file you *must* write special code to handle this.  FileInputStreams will not work.

Comment: Thanks but I don't see what I need to add. When I do a simple clean-and-build in netbeans, and then run the compiled jar from the /dist folder, the reports work just fine and output the correct fonts. But when I compile into a single fat jar I get this error. What could be the difference?

Answer (score 0):

@eoinDub:
I had a similar problem when loading the report itselfes from the class directory of the fat jar. So I used "...**getResourceAsStream**()".
I did something like this (see code below). [Actually I used a compiled *.jasper - I don't remember whether an uncompiled *.jrxml did work, too.]

```
        JasperReport report = null;

    InputStream is = MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(reportName);
    if (FilenameUtils.isExtension(reportName, "jrxml")) {
        JasperDesign jd = JRXmlLoader.load(is);

        report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jd);

    } else {
        report = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(is);
    }

    JRCsvDataSource ds;
    try {
        ds = new JRCsvDataSource(csvName, csvEncoding);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }

    ds.setUseFirstRowAsHeader(true);
    ds.setFieldDelimiter(csvDelimiter.charAt(0));

    JasperPrint jprint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, reportParams, ds);

    try {
        JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jprint, outPDF);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck with the same problem. In my project I am using Maven, and I noticed that at the end of generating the fat .jar, it threw a message of

```
jasperreports_extension.properties already added, skipping
```

Among what I saw on the web about this problem, I got that this file is repeated in several libraries, such as: jasperreports and jasperfonts; this causes conflicts between them and the Maven ignores them. So what I did was put my custom `jasperreports_extension.properties` file among the first Maven dependency files, so that this file setting takes it first.