# Java: application runs on eclipse but miss jars after exporting it

Tags: java, eclipse, jasper-reports

my swing application run perfectly fine inside eclipse 
but when I export it to "Executable jar" I get this exception when I try to print something using `JasperReports`:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-6" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.<init>(JRBaseFiller.java:97)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.<init>(JRVerticalFiller.java:74)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.<init>(JRVerticalFiller.java:62)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.createBandReportFiller(JRFiller.java:187)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.createReportFiller(JRFiller.java:202)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:110)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:584)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:930)
        at smt.agm.launcher.SmartPaieLauncher$2.run(SmartPaieLauncher.java:94)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Input stream not found at : fonts.xml
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontExtensionHelper.loadFontFamilies(SimpleFontExtensionHelper.java:188)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.FontExtensionsRegistry.getExtensions(FontExtensionsRegistry.java:56)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.extensions.DefaultExtensionsRegistry.getExtensions(DefaultExtensionsRegistry.java:110)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRStyledTextParser.<clinit>(JRStyledTextParser.java:83)
        ... 10 more
Caused by: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Input stream not found at : fonts.xml
        at net.sf.jasperreports.repo.RepositoryUtil.getInputStreamFromLocation(RepositoryUtil.java:159)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontExtensionHelper.loadFontFamilies(SimpleFontExtensionHelper.java:183)
```

Why is this happening ?!

**EDIT**:
I'm using `JasperReports` inside `ProjectX` and this `ProjectX` is using another java project let's call it `ProjectY`
inside both projects I'm using `JasperReports` jars
The exception no longer exist when I remove `JasperReports` from `ProjectY`.
what is the explanation of this ?
and how can I use `JasperReports` inside `ProjectY` ?

Comment: its bit confusing...JasperReports  jar is with ProjectX  or ProjectY or with both?

Comment: If the file `fonts.xml` is located in the project directory, move it into the source folder (probably `src`). If not, please tell, where `fonts.xml` is located, if it is included in the JAR and how it is loaded.

Comment: it's seem like you are combing multiple jars in ProjectY, I suggest you check your classpath, maybe you have also a "fat" jar somewhere.

Comment: this is related https://stackoverflow.com/q/24961180/5292302

Comment: @Prasobh.K the jar is with both of them.

Comment: @howlger I don't know where this file is, in fact I have never seen it before and `ProjectX` was working perfectly fine until I added JasperReports to `ProjectY`

Comment: @PetterFriberg what do you mean using multiple jars ? of course I'm using many jars in both projects.

Comment: I mean multiple libs of jasper reports, different version?, some jar compiled as "fat" jar? Try to investigate what you have in class path, it obviously have problem loading that file from classpath